# How to change int to datetime in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am getting the following erorr `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'datetime.date'`

my code is `np.where((Manual_Dialling['Text_Date'] > Manual_Dialling['set_date']) & (Manual_Dialling['Text_Date'] < Manual_Dialling['set_date_2']), 1, 0)`

I tried converting

```
Manual_Dialling['Text_Date'] = Manual_Dialling['Text_Date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x), format='%Y%m%d'))
```

It gave me error as : `ValueError: time data '2021-10-08 00:00:00' does not match format '%Y%m%d' (match)`

How do I compare the three dates mentioned in `np.where` ?

Comment: `Manual_Dialling['Text_Date'] = Manual_Dialling['Text_Date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x)))` - I don't believe you need to formatting if it is already formatted ...

Comment: Just remove the formatting option, or make it compatible with `'2021-10-08 00:00:00'`

Comment: @alec_djinn it is already compatible - running the code I gave above worked easily.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `print(df.loc[['Text_Date', 'set_date', 'set_date_2']].head(5).to_string())` please?

Comment: What is `print (df.dtypes)` ?

Comment: Also @coder_bg if you were to format it like you want it, you would have to do `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`

Answer (score 0):

Convert all columns to datetimes and then create mask by [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
Manual_Dialling['Text_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Manual_Dialling['Text_Date'])
Manual_Dialling['set_date'] = pd.to_datetime(Manual_Dialling['set_date'].astype(str))
Manual_Dialling['set_date_2'] = pd.to_datetime(Manual_Dialling['set_date_2'].astype(str))

m = Manual_Dialling['Text_Date'].between(Manual_Dialling['set_date'],
                                         Manual_Dialling['set_date_2'], inclusive=False)

out = np.where(m, 1, 0)
out = m.astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can read pandas pandas.to_datetime.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime